# Colorize structured text in emacs org mode in html export

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode, colorize

Is there a way to preserve the colors of a structured document in emacs org-mode when exported to a html file?

Answer (score 1):

After researching for a while, I found that adding the following in the header section of the org file enables the colors that I wanted in an exported html.

```
    #+STYLE:html { font-family:Consolas; font-size: 14pt; }
    #+STYLE:pre {font-family: Consolas; font-weight: bold; font-size:14pt} 
    #+STYLE:.title { text-align: center; color: green; font-family: Consolas; color:#0000FF} 
    #+STYLE:h2 { font-family: Consolas; color:#0000FF} 
    #+STYLE:h3 { font-family: Consolas; color:#FF00FF} 
    #+STYLE:h4 { font-family: Consolas; color:#9900FF}
```

Comment: I don't know why the enclosing <style>...</style> tag is being removed here!

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick, give it a go:
[Htmlize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize)

As it states:

> "You can use this package to render code snippets with syntax highlighting when exporting Org-mode files to HTML."

Comment: I got the code syntax highlighting working. I was asking about colorizing the heading levels as it appears in the org-mode. These appear in black when exported to html and it would be nice to have different colors for heading levels. I apologize for not making it clear!

Comment: If the heading levels aren't to complex you can try changing the CSS file manually, see what classes need the altering in your exported html file..
http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support
This gives you information on what each class is used for

Comment: If the headings appear in HTML differently colorized than in the buffer, that could indicate a bug in `htmlize`. You could try to report it to the author.